# Is there a way in R to filter data from one dataframe based on a range from a different dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataset from video re-coding with a wide array of data recorded alongside the timing of the video in milliseconds. I also have the specific frame numbers of the sections of the video I am interested in, in a separate CSV file. I am hoping to make a new dataset with only the data that falls within my regions of interest.

I have currently done this manually by pulling out the times from my first dataframe and typing them in (example below). I have then re-combined the dataframes using rbind, but this is not realistic to conitinue doing given the amount of data I have. I really appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

`data1 <- dplyr::filter(data, between(data$start.time, 379909, 387176))`

`data2 <- dplyr::filter(data, between(data$start.time, 398802, 406488))`

Comment: Hi Madeline, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide us with more infromation about your datasets? Otherwise it's quite hard to figure out a solution for your problem. Simply type dput(NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASET) into the console and paste the output as code into your question. As your dataset is probably large, it is best to give us just a snippet of your data, e.g. for the first 10 rows dput(NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASET[1:10, ]) will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map2` to loop over the vectors and `filter` the data

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
lst1 <- map2(c(379909, 398802), c(387176, 406488), ~ data %>%
            filter(between(start.time, .x, .y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly how your data is structured, but perhaps this may be helpful. If I'm off on this, my apologies (and will promptly remove answer).

Say you have two data frames, one with `start` and `end` times in msec, and the second with specific `start.time` msec values.

With `dplyr` you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

vid_data %>%
  mutate(flag = 1) %>%
  full_join(data %>% mutate(flag = 1), by = "flag") %>%
  dplyr::filter(between(start.time, start, end)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  dplyr::select(-flag)
```

With a lot of data, you can do something faster with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(vid_data)
setDT(data)

vid_data[data, on = .(start < start.time, end > start.time), .(id, frame, start.time), nomatch = 0]
```

**Sample Data**:

```
vid_data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  start = c(380000, 398000, 401000),
  end = c(387000, 406000, 412000)
)

data <- data.frame(
  frame = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  start.time = c(379000,381000,385000,403000,410000)
)
```

**Output**: With `dplyr` and `data.table` respectively:

```
id  start    end frame start.time
1  1 380000 387000     2     381000
2  1 380000 387000     3     385000
3  2 398000 406000     4     403000
4  3 401000 412000     4     403000
5  3 401000 412000     5     410000

   id frame start.time
1:  1     2     381000
2:  1     3     385000
3:  2     4     403000
4:  3     4     403000
5:  3     5     410000
```